# Swift WKWebView programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, webview, wkwebview

I'd like to generate a WKWebView with a specific size programmatically.

This code is what I got so far:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let webview = WKWebView()
    webview.frame  = CGRect(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 150) // not working
    webview.load(URLRequest(url: (forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "myfolder")! as URL) as URLRequest)
    webview.uiDelegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(webview)
}
```

but it doesn't seems working that way.

> ERROR: "**Cannot convert value of type '(forResource: String, withExtension: String, subdirectory: String)' to type 'URL' in coercion**"

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: It would really help if you explained what is actually happening versus what you expect to happen.

Comment: And please don't needlessly use `NSURL` or `NSURLRequest`. Just use `URL` and `URLRequest`.

Comment: You would greatly benefit from splitting that "load" line into about three or four lines each doing only one thing.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the solution on my own:

This code is working quite fine:

```
let webview = WKWebView()
    webview.frame  = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100)
    webview.load(URLRequest(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension:"html", subdirectory: "subdirectories")! as URL) as URLRequest)
    self.view.addSubview(webview)
```

--

This was the line I was missing:

```
url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension:"html", subdirectory: "subdirectories")! as URL)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.** Create a constant object of WKWebView type as shown below

```
private let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
```

In viewDidLoad() method add webView to View.

```
      webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       self.view.addSubview(self.webView)
    // You can set constant space for Left, Right, Top and Bottom Anchors
                        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                            self.webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
                            self.webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
                            self.webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
                            self.webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
                            ])
        // For constant height use the below constraint and set your height constant and remove either top or bottom constraint
        //self.webView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
        
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL.init(string: "https://www.google.com"))
        self.webView.load(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let startScript = Bundle(for: Background.self).url(forResource: "my_js_script", withExtension: "js")!
    let scripts =         do {
        return try String(contentsOf: startScript, encoding: .utf8)
    }
    catch {
        let message = "Could not load file at: \(startScript)"
        fatalError(message)
    }
    let script = WKUserScript(source: scripts, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)

    let contentController: WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()
    contentController.addUserScript(script)

    contentController.add(self, name: "backgroundListener")
    webConfiguration.userContentController = contentController

    self._webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    self._webView!.customUserAgent = "my-Bridge"
    let html : String = """
                         <html>
                           <head></head>
                           <body></body>
                         </html>
                        """;
    self._webView!.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: Could you add some description to this answer to add some context for this coding solution?